Is Unique Games on hypergraphs NP-hard?
My overall question is about whether we know stronger variants of the unique games conjecture which are proven to be NP-hard? I am aware of the 2-2 Games Conjecture result.
For instance:
Given a 3-uniform 3-partite hypergraph $G = (V, E)$, an alphabet $\Sigma$, and a set of permutations $\pi_{uv}, \pi_{uw}$ for each hyperedge $e = (u, v, w) \in E$. We say that an edge is satisfied if there is a label function $l: V \rightarrow \Sigma$ such that $l(u) = \pi_{uv}(l(v)) = \pi_{uw}(l(w))$. For any $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$, is there an hypergraph $G = (V, E)$ such that it is NP-hard to decide whether

(Completeness): There is a labeling that satisfies $1 - \varepsilon$ of the edges
(Soundness): All labelings satisfy at most $\delta$ of the edges.

Remark: There could be other ways of extending the problem to hypergraphs, so any pointer to another variant would be interesting.
